# Ubuntu '-bash: nano: command not found'

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04, mod-security

I am trying to use Ubuntu 18.04 to download ModSecurity on Google Cloud, but whenever I try writing `sudo nano *file*.conf` or `nano *file*.conf`. I get an error saying `-bash: nano: command not found` or `sudo: nano: command not found`. I'm not sure if it is because I'm using Google Cloud Platform for this, but I just need to know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try running `sudo apt-get install nano`

It appears nano isn't installed on your machine

Comment: I thought nano came preinstalled on ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error. The fix to this is that the nano text editor is missing in your OS.
You can download it by writing this in the terminal window:

```
sudo apt install nano
```

***Note***: The apt-get would also work but it is depreciated now and the new term is apt.

Answer (score 3):

Seems **nano** is missing on this ubuntu.

Try: *sudo apt-get install nano*